# Как достать информацию из скрипта внутри html

Tags: java, jsoup, парсер

Коллеги, приветствую.

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как можно достать необходимую информацию из javascript, если я правильно понимаю.

Хочу сделать приложение, которое будет идентично браузерному, только на десктоп. Логика? просто для опыта.

Сайт:http://live.podryad.tv/vsaas/cameras
На данный момент используя jsoup добился того, что не могу получить вот эти значения:

```
<div class="camera-list-container">
```

и все его содержимое.

Как я понял из html, все содержимое div`ов берется из скриптов:

```
<script src="/vsaas/static/js/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/vsaas/static/js/lib/jquery/jquery.typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="/vsaas/static/js/lib/jquery/jquery.addresspicker.js"></script>
<script src="/vsaas/static/js/lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="/vsaas/static/js/lib/leaflet/layer/Layer.Deferred.js"></script>
```

Из какого точно, я не очень понимаю, но на данный момент это не главное. Я не понимаю, даже как доставать эти значения ( div`ы в смысле).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы я использовал phantomjsdriver совместно с selenium. Очень удобно. Имитирует загрузку браузера в текстовом формате и, следовательно, все скрипты уже загружены на страницу и их можно "просматривать" и делать то, что необходимо.